# How to create mipmaps based on maximum value rather than default merging?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I have a 3D texture. Each texel contains a transparency value on the alpha channel.

I need to generate my mipmaps in such a way that it always takes the values of the texel with he maximum alpha value.

In other words if there are 4 texels 3 with a transparency value of 0 and one with a transparency value of 1 the resulting mipmap texel should be 1.

How can I achieve this?

If I need to write my own shaders, what is the optimal way to do it?

EDIT:

My question, to put it more clearly is:

Do I need to manually create a shader that does this or is there a way to use built in functions of opengl to save me the trouble?

Comment: "*How can I achieve this?*" It's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for here. The way you achieve this is to write the code to do it. Are you asking if there's a pre-made OpenGL solution? Are you asking for an on-GPU solution? What's the question here? Also, 3D textures generate mipmaps in three dimensions. So each lower-level mipmap represents *eight* texels from the higher mipmap, not 4.

Comment: [`ARB_texture_filter_minmax`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_texture_filter_minmax.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that,  you'll need to render to each layer of each mipmap with a custom shader that computes max of 8 samples from the upper level.
This can be done by attaching each layer of the rendered mipmap to a framebuffer (using `glFramebufferTexture3D`), and, in the shader,  sampling from the same texture by using `texelFetch` (`lod` parameter specifies the mipmap to sample from).